# Middleware not returning error details to API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, jwt

I have a API project in asp.net core and I have a middleware that handle JWT authentication.

This is the method that validates the token

```
private void attachAccountToContext(HttpContext context, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                byte[] encodedKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWTSecretKey"]);
                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encodedKey),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(ex.Message);
            }
```

If the token is expired I get a message in console and inside the `catch` statement, but when I make the request from Postman, after publishing the project, it returns error 500 no matter what I `throw`.

I would like to return the error message to the client but I don't know how to pass it out the middleware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get an error in development environment, this error will be shown. After publishing your app, these pure error messages should be hidden from client side for security purpose. You can write your own exception middleware to return exception to client side without security risk and only information purpose;

```
    public class ExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate _next;

        public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, e);
            }
        }

        private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception e)
        {
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails
            {
                StatusCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode,
                Message = e.Message
            }.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then you have to register it to `IApplicationBuilder` as a extension method

```
public static class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
     public static void ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
     {
         app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
     }
}
```

Then you have to register it inside of `Startup.cs -> Configure` method as a:

```
   app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();
```

After these configurations any threw exception will be returned to client side with message and status code.

Comment: Thank you I'll try ASAP, just one more thing. Do I have to `configure` this middleware before or after the JWT one? I've encountered problems with the configure pipeline

Comment: It worked, if someone needs it in the future: in the `configure` method the exception middleware must be added before JWT middleware